# How to make multiple jquery functions into just one function?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, asp.net, json

i have a code like below:-

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tableA").on("click", function () {
         $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "Testing.ashx",
         success: function (output) {
            output = JSON.parse(output);
            DrawTableA(output);
            }
         })
    });

     $("#tableB").on("click", function () {
         $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "Testing.ashx",
         success: function (output) {
            output = JSON.parse(output);
            DrawTableB(output);
            }
         })
    });          

}

<table id=tableA>tableA</table>
<table id=tableB>tableB</table>
```

and im hoping to make it only into one function instead of using two function as the attributes are all the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly you can join the selectors with a comma to combine the event handlers. The only difference from there is the function which gets called in the `success` function. Assuming the logic there is the same too you could pass the table as an argument:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#tableA, #tableB").on("click", function () {
     let $table = $(this);
     $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: "Testing.ashx",
       success: function (output) {
         let output = JSON.parse(output);
         DrawTable($table, output);
       }
    })
  });
});
```

If, for whatever reason, you need to execute completely different logic on each `table` element, then you could store the function name in a `data` attribute on the table HTML. Then you can define the functions within an object, keyed by the value of that attribute:

```js
let tableFuncs = {
  foo: () => console.log('tableA'),
  bar: () => console.log('tableB')
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tableA, #tableB").on("click", function() {
    let $table = $(this);
    
    // inside AJAX callback...
    tableFuncs[$table.data('func')]();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="tableA" data-func="foo">
  <tr>
    <td>tableA</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="tableB" data-func="bar">
  <tr>
    <td>tableB</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Also, as pointed out by @PeterSH in the comments, it's better practice to use common classes on repeated elements to make the code easier to maintain. With your current pattern, if you add a `#tableC` in the future you would need to remember to amend the JS as well. If you select by a class you just need to remember to include the class in the HTML only.

Comment: It might be better to have a class selector, if more tables are added in the future. `$(".drawTable").on("click", function () {})`

Comment: Very good point, thanks. I added a note about it in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

i think something like this would work

```
$("#tableB, #tableA").on("click", function () {
    var targetTable = $(this);
         $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "Testing.ashx",
         success: function (output) {
            output = JSON.parse(output);
            if(targetTable.attr('id') === 'tableA') {
             DrawTableA(output);
            } else {
             DrawTableB(output);
            }
            }
         })
    });
```

just use `,` delimiter for each target element

Edit: use the attribute id on which table being clicked to and then call a function for that table for rendering

Comment: `DrawTableA()` and `DrawTableB()`, though

Comment: @noobHere the function in the ajax is different, its DrawTableA() and DrawTableB()

Comment: you can check the attr.id and call the specific function for that.. see edited answer

Comment: guys this is my new thread, 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63170853/how-to-simplify-multiple-jquery-functions-into-just-one-function

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use this code for helpful 

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tableA, #tableB").on("click", function () {
         $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "Testing.ashx",
         success: function (output) {
            output = JSON.parse(output);
            DrawTableA(output);
            }
         })
    });

}

<table id=tableA>tableA</table>
<table id=tableB>tableB</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Will work for all ids starting with the table:-

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$("[id^=table]").on("click", function () {
 let $table = $(this);
     $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "Testing.ashx",
     success: function (output) {
        output = JSON.parse(output);
        DrawTable($table,output);
        }
     })
});        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it this way and it works.

```
            $(".tableToggle").on("click", function () {
                var tableType = $(this).attr('data-tableid');
                var fName = "DrawTable" + tableType;
                $('body').append('<div id="loadingDiv"><div class="lds"><div></div><div></div><div></div></div></div>');
                if (($("#tb2" + tableType + " tr").length) > 0) {
                        $("#tb1" + tableType).toggleClass("accordion accordion2");
                        $("#tb2" + tableType).toggle();
                        $("#loadingDiv").remove();
                    
                }
                else {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "AccInfoTest.ashx",
                        data: { itemType : tableType},
                        success: function (output) {
                            try {
                                output = JSON.parse(output);
                                window[fName](output);
                            }
                            catch (ex) {
                                alert("error");
                                $('#tb2' + tableType).empty();
                            }
                        }
                        , complete: function (data) {

                                $("#tb2" + tableType).show();
                                $("#tb1" + tableType).addClass("accordion2").removeClass("accordion");
                                $("#loadingDiv").remove();
                            
                        }
                    })
                }
            });
```